# Suggestion with aggregation of data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello i have a data frame with more than 3632200+ obs, and I'm trying to find some useful information out of it. I have cleaned it a bit so now this is what the data looks like

```
                 Order      Lane                Days
                 18852324   796005 - Ahmedabad  2
                 232313     796008 - Delhi      5
                 63963231   796005 - Ahmedabad  5
                 23501231   788152 - Chennai    1
                 2498732    796008 - Delhi      2
                 231413     796005 - Ahmedabad  3
                 75876876   796012 - Chennai    4
                 14598676   796008 - Delhi      4
```

Order are different Order Id's, they all are unique, Lane are different paths on which the order was delivered(Lanes can repeat for various orders) & Days is calculated using difftime function in R by differentiating Order delivered and created date.

Now What I'm trying to achieve is something like this

[image: Final Output]

Now I can calculate 98.% order achieved date by using quantile function in R across various lane.
But how do I achieve % of orders fulfilled by day 1 to 5 across various lanes?
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: do you have reproducible, example data, ideally for before, preferably for after also? Very hard to provide a code solution without that.

Comment: Hi i have added an example data, the before data is having 76 columns and I dont think would be of any use for our problem here.

Comment: Hi - the general guidelines are to use `dput` or similar to allow for reimporting of data rather than type in from a screenshot.  Can you `dput`the subset of your data from the screenshot please?

Comment: Hi i have tried editing it again. I hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: I can't work out the question. How do difftimes between 44.13 and 48.95 days equate to day 1 thru day 5? How do you define an order as achieved? Feel like I may have missed something but it's not obvious to me where to start.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i have changed the confusing days to towards more suitable for our example. Actually days is the total time it took for the order delivery for a particular order on a particular lane. I want to find out how many % of orders were delivered on day 1 on a particular lane and so on upto how many % of orders were delivered by day 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188187/discussion-between-anshul-gupta-and-nycrefugee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without the data, but maybe something like this:

```
library(purrr)
#df = your data
max_days = max(df$days)

aggregate_fun = function(x){
  days = factor(x$days,levels=c(1:max_days))
  prop.table(table(days))
}

df = split(df,df$lane)

results = reduce(lapply(df,aggregate_fun),rbind)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer. Just a question why are we doing this ? 

                            df = split(df,df$lane)

Comment: To separate the data frame into lists containing only the observations for one lane. Then we can use `table` to calculate the percentage of days for each lane separately

Comment: Thank you so much.